# SVN Export Folder Files Only

Tags: svn

I have a folder in a repository:

```
svn/Repo/trunk/Folder
```

And I want to export all the files in `Folder` to a local directory:

```
C:\AnotherFolder
```

If I do an export from the repository to the local folder, it exports all files including the parent folder, so I end up with the structure:

```
C:\AnotherFolder\Folder\file1 
C:\AnotherFolder\Folder\file2 
etc
```

How can I export without the parent directory? So I get something like:

```
C:\AnotherFolder\file1 
C:\AnotherFolder\file2
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to do that with the following SVN command:

```
svn export http://.../svn/Repo/trunk/Folder C:\AnotherFolder
```

This should also work with a relative path for AnotherFolder like this:

```
svn export http://.../svn/Repo/trunk/Folder AnotherFolder
```

Comment: You are right. I'm trying to do this in Visual Build Pro and I assumed that was the command it was using. I guess not. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want to export a file ,the command is
svn export http://.../svn/Repo/trunk/filename C:\AnotherFolder\filename

Comment: Thanks Frank, your answer helped me with my problem though it wasn't a proper answer to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `./` path for current folder where command is run:

```
svn export http://.../svn/Repo/trunk/Folder ./
```